# DRF pagination with filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework project which is serving up (amongst other things) events.

In general, as there could be thousands of events, I prefer to keep the API calls paginated in order to stop the front end API calls from taking too long.

I can use this paginated route to produce a table on the front end which will reflect each page in the returned response.

Up until now, all good.

However, I also want to add a dropdown filter above the table where users can select any of the possible venues that the events are at. But to get an exhaustive list of all the possible venues for the dropdown list, I'll need to go and fetch ALL of the events anyway!

Is there another way to do this? Or is a non-paginated events route my only choice?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `django rest framework` documentation, in [Filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) section

Comment: Ah, maybe I didn't make myself clear. It's not the filtering I have a problem with. It's getting hold of the options that the filtering can use. I want a dropdown list of all the possible venues to allow the users to filter on them. But in order to get that list, I need to get all of the events, not just the first page. Make sense?

Comment: Achievable, but you'll need a lot.
i have done this before using `channels+websockets+Indexdb`.

Answer (score 0):

If the venue requires all the events (thousands) it will not be a good idea to fetch it in the frontend, Try to deal with that from the backend and serve venues in the frontend based on the requirements.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? Are you suggesting that the API should provide a route which would return a list of all the possible venues?

Comment: Yes, not all but paginated venues. You can handle that pagination in the dropdown by scrolling events. I am answering based on the observation from your question ( I do not know your data structure).